# Trigger state hooks from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a bottom drawer component `BottomSheetComponent` that I was able to toggle from a button at the top of the page with a state hook. After clicking the button to toggle the drawer into view. However, I'm unable to trigger the drawer closed from the drawer itself using the svg icon, and unable to figure out how to pass the state hook from the parents component `App` to the child component `BottomSheetComponent` to trigger the close from the child component.

How to toggle the child component closed from the svg of the child component?

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }

  return (
    <div classNameName="App">
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Toggle Bottom Sheet</button>
      {toggle && <BottomSheetComponent toggle={toggle} header="My Custom Title" subHeader="Some more information here">
      This is the body of the component
      </BottomSheetComponent>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**BottomSheetComponent.js**

```
import { useSpring, animated, interpolate, config } from "react-spring/hooks";
const BottomSheet = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const theme = useTheme();
    const classes = useStyles({ theme })

    return (
       <div className={classes.bottomSheetContainer} style={{transform: 'translateY(calc(-40vh + 0px))'}}>
            <div className={classes.headerDragger}></div>
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                className={classes.closeButton} style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 16, top: 16 }}>
                <path d="M17.2929 18.7071C17.6834 19.0976 18.3166 19.0976 18.7071 18.7071C19.0976 18.3166 19.0976 17.6834 18.7071 17.2929L13.4142 12L18.7071 6.70711C19.0976 6.31658 19.0976 5.68342 18.7071 5.29289C18.3166 4.90237 17.6834 4.90237 17.2929 5.29289L12 10.5858L6.70711 5.29289C6.31658 4.90237 5.68342 4.90237 5.29289 5.29289C4.90237 5.68342 4.90237 6.31658 5.29289 6.70711L10.5858 12L5.29289 17.2929C4.90237 17.6834 4.90237 18.3166 5.29289 18.7071C5.68342 19.0976 6.31658 19.0976 6.70711 18.7071L12 13.4142L17.2929 18.7071Z" fill="#191919"></path></svg>
            <h1 className={classes.header}>{props.header}</h1>
            <h2 className={classes.subHeader}>{props.subHeader}</h2>
            <div>
                <div className={classes.contentContainer}>
                    <div style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(rgb(230, 100, 101), rgb(145, 152, 229))', height: 800 }}>
                        <h1 style={{ color: '#ffffff', padding: 8, fontSize: 18 }}>
                            {props.children}
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Current state of component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sky-n098b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `handleToggle` function to the child, and set it as `onClick` handler of the SVG file:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const BottomSheetComponent = ({ children, toggle }) => (
  <div>
    <svg
      onClick={toggle}
      height="24" width="24">
        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="black" strokeWidth="3" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
);

function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    <button onClick={handleToggle}>Toggle Bottom Sheet</button>
      {toggle && <BottomSheetComponent toggle={handleToggle} header="My Custom Title" subHeader="Some more information here">
      This is the body of the component
      </BottomSheetComponent>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Since BottomShelfComponent is imported into `App.js`, how can I pass the prop to the child component? When I try, the page goes blank.

Comment: You should pass it as a prop (for example - `toggle={handleToggle}` in my code).

Comment: I'm passing `toggle={handleToggle}` into `<BottomSheetComponent/>`, and then using `<svg onClick={toggle}/>`, but it's not triggering the component to close.

Comment: Replace `onClick={toggle}` with `onClick={() => console.log('click')}`, and see if the word click appears in the console. If it does, you're probably passing the wrong function. If it doesn't try to wrap it with a button component, and pass the `onClick` to the button.

Comment: I was able to log out `click`, but I'm passing `toggle` from the parent `toggle={handleToggle}` to the child and the child is using `<svg onClick={toggle}/>` which should trigger the function to toggle the child closed, but it's not.

Comment: The `onClick` on the svg works. Try to push the console.log on the `toggle` you pass to in, and see if it works, and so on.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to a codesandbox with the current state of the component and how it's passing the state prop but not triggering the close. Here's a link to it as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-sky-n098b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: You have two errors: 1. Change  `setToggle={handleToggle}` to `toggle={handleToggle}`. 
 2. In `BottomSheetComponent` definition, use spread to pass all props to `BottomSheet` - `<BottomSheet {...props} />`. Right now you don't pass the toggle prop. - https://codesandbox.io/s/small-snow-67qub?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Updated the codesandbox with your recommendations, but maybe I'm not passing the props in correctly?

Comment: Look at my sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/small-snow-67qub?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Similarly how you passed toggle as a prop you can pass the setToggle as a prop to a child. The child in this case being your BottomSheetComponent. Calling your handleToggle should update the state.

If you're struggle to have the svg trigger it. You can wrap it with a button and when the event bubbles up have the button catch the event. You can stop the propagation and then handle the logic there.

Answer (score 0):

For child-parent communication, you should pass a function setting the state from parent to child and whenever you trigger that function the state will be updated.